# llvm dev package missing libclangBasic

Tags: package-management, compiling

(Using 19.10 fully uptodate)

I am using cmake to build emacs irony server

`Cmake` is further loading a llvm cmake file;

```
/usr/lib/llvm-8/lib/cmake/clang/ClangTargets.cmake
```

and this tests for existence of file

```
/usr/lib/llvm-8/lib/libclangBasic.a
```

This is the same for `llvm-9` package. 
So my conclusion is that the packaging of `llvm dev` is broken and has been broken for sometime,
I have seen other people report this broken package as well.

Other than downloading llvm/clang and building is there a workaround.

Additionally, can you fix the package going forward?

Answer (score 20):

If anyone is interested i found the solution to my own problem!

Stupidly I was missing a further clang-dev package install.
I had convinced myself there was a problem with my install as i had seen 
the identical issue talk about on the Web.

Comment: It's `libclang-dev` or `libclang-9-dev` in my case.

Comment: This solved the problem in my case!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years later, the problem keeps reappearing: if several versions of Clang or LLVM are installed on a system, CMake will search for `libclangBasic.a` in the wrong place.

Obvious solution: purge all outdated Clang and LLVM packages.

If feasible, don't manually install any packages with version number in their names. Only use generic packages like `llvm-dev`, `libclang-dev`.